# My Node Api is missing records randomly in reactjs but when I try on postman its works fine

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, api, express

I created the Nodejs with express mongoose for the API's and when I try to fetch the products it behaves very abnormally to me. For example, I'm requesting 4 products then it responds me only 2 products and something 1 and something 4 products. I'm confused why this is happing.

[My Api Link](https://backend.websouls.com/api/currencies/packages?p_id%5B%5D=184&p_id%5B%5D=107&p_id%5B%5D=130&p_id%5B%5D=280)

The Above Link is the API of the fectching products with Get Method. If I run this api in post its works fine and if I run this on the reactjs application then the data missed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLYDK.png)

As you can see in this Image, I'm requesting for 4 products and It gives me only 3.

That's the function I'm using for the API's.

```
exports.getPackages = async function (req, res) {
  const pids = req.query.p_id;
  let newObject = [];

  let obj = {};
  for (i = 0; i < pids.length; i++) {
    let cr = [];
    const package = await priceModel
      .find({ pid: pids[i] })
      .select({ pro_config_options: 0 });
    //res.json(package);
    const packageFeatures = await featuresModel
      .find({ pid: pids[i] })
      .select({ pid: 0 });
    //res.json(packageFeatures);
    for (j = 0; j < package.length; j++) {
      let ccr = {
        currency: package[j].currency,
        annually: package[j].annually,
        biennially: package[j].biennially,
        triennially: package[j].triennially,
        monthly: package[j].monthly,
        quarterly: package[j].quarterly,
        semiannually: package[j].semiannually,
        qsetupfee: package[j].qsetupfee,
        ssetupfee: package[j].ssetupfee,
        asetupfee: package[j].asetupfee,
        bsetupfee: package[j].bsetupfee,
        tsetupfee: package[j].tsetupfee,
      };
      cr.push(ccr);
    }

    obj = {
      id: package[0]._id,
      pid: package[0].pid,
      name: package[0].name,
      title: package[0].title,
      tid: "",
      fname: package[0].fname,
      currency: cr,
      addons: [],
      freedomain: [],
      packageFeatures,
      addonids: package[0].addonids,
    };
    // res.json(obj);
    newObject.push(obj);
    //package.push(newObject);
  }
  res.json(newObject);
};
```

The above code is fecthing and generating the objects for my frontend. It fecth the multiple data from the model.

Kindly if anyone know how to fix this please letme know. Thank you.

I tried a lot but nothing happened. Firstly I think it's on my frontend issue but I tried multiple things like react query, fetch, Axios, etc for API calling but same it's giving me random data.

Comment: console.log(pids) and look what comes out.

I would send the array with the body and then in my query do something like find with an only statement. What ORM/DB are you using.

Comment: @Ralle I tried to find the error via consoling the pids as you said and I got the issue on some other api where the pid data is not coming in a right way. I'm using Mongoose as a db.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "some other apis"?

Comment: This means all of the APIs receive the bids from params and just only one API is sending the wrong information. Btw if you don't mind can you drop your skype id?